# Convert Image Datatype in sqlserver to Byte[] in Linq anonymous object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm facing problem while converting image datatype to byte[]. Please give me a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Susan.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the LockBits method. Check out:

[LockBits()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229672.aspx)